# Basic authentication with JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, basic-authentication

The JSON page I'm requesting requires a password and username both of type string. The Username and password belong to the developer... By the way it is able to reach the page I just can't get past the authentication.

This is the api url: https://api.intrinio.com/prices?identifier=AAPL

If I've left out some information or code let me know and I'll provide it.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    //MARK: - Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var labelTwo: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tickerTextField: UITextField!

    //MARK: - Properties
    let userPasswordString = ""
    let userPassword = ""

    //MARK: - View Did Load
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        tickerTextField.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        tickerTextField.text = "Search Ticker"
        tickerTextField.delegate = self

        let jsonUrlString = "https://api.intrinio.com/prices?identifier=\(ticker)"
        print(jsonUrlString)
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            let dataAsString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
            print(dataAsString!)
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                let tickerPrice = try jsonDecoder.decode(TickerPrice.self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   print(tickerPrice.name)
                }
            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error serielaising jason", jsonErr)
            }
            }.resume()

    }
```

Comment: http://docs.intrinio.com/#authentication You need to add headers with the login/password.

Comment: If I understood correctly (take account of the logic, not the "Swift bad coding with unwrapped, etc.): `var request = URLRequest.init(url: url!); let userName = "API_USERNAME"; let password = "API_PASSWORD"; let toEncode = "\(userName):\(password)"; let encoded = toEncode.data(using: .utf8)?.base64EncodedString(); request.addValue("Basic \(encoded!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")`. Then `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){}` instead of `(with: url)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.intrinio.com/#authentication):

> Private To authorize your access to the Intrinio API:
>
> ```
> // With shell, you must include the username and 
> // password header
> curl "https://api.intrinio.com/data_point?identifier=AAPL&item=close_price"
>   -u "API_USERNAME:API_PASSWORD"
>
> // With the '-u' option in curl, it will automatically
> // convert the username and password into the 
> // appropriate header. If you do not use this 
> // option or it is not available to you, you must 
> // include a header with the basic auth credentials 
> // included as base64 encoded.
> curl "https://api.intrinio.com/data_point?identifier=AAPL&item=close_price"
>   -H "Authorization: Basic $BASE64_ENCODED(API_USERNAME:API_PASSWORD)"
> ```
>
> For private/trusted environments, use Basic Authentication over HTTPS.
>
> You can find your API Username and API Password on your Account page.
>   You must include these credentials with every request in order to
>   receive access to the API.
>
> To include the credentials in your HTTPS request, specify an
>   Authorization header, with the value Basic (key), replacing (key) with
>   the Base-64 encoded string API_USERNAME:API_PASSWORD.
>
> If your credentials are not authorized, a status code of 401 will be
>   returned.
>
> You must replace API_USERNAME and API_PASSWORD with your API keys
>   found on your API Admin Dashboard.

So to do that, you need to use a `URLRequest` and not only a `URL`:

```
//Create URLRequest
var request = URLRequest.init(url: url!)

//Create Header according to the documentation
let userName = "API_USERNAME" //Need to be replaced with correct value
let password = "API_PASSWORD" //Need to be replaced with correct value
let toEncode = "\(userName):\(password)" //Form the String to be encoded
let encoded = toEncode.data(using: .utf8)?.base64EncodedString()

//Add the header value
request.addValue("Basic \(encoded!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

//Perform the task with the request instead of previously the URL
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){//The rest of your code}
```

Side note, I didn't do `guard let` or `if let`, I ugly unwrapped when needed. It's to show the main logic and the CocoaTouch API rather than anything else, especially since I'm not a Swift developer.